# Resolve write after read race condition

Tags: database, postgresql, concurrency, race-condition

Here is a race condition scenario that I need help with:

We are trying to create Item A and item B in the DB and we want to persist that item B is a "childOf" item A. Let's assume the request to create item B along with the "childOf" relationship data arrives before request to create item A.

here are the steps assuming a single job process these requests one at a time

- Request to create item B arrives first with the "childOf" relationship data that says item B is a child of item A
- First, we check if item A exists
- If item A exists item B is created and a "childOf" relationship record is created between item B and item A
- **If item A doesn't exist, the process creates a pending record in the db saying item A is not yet created**
- When a request to create item A arrives, item A is created, the db is checked for any "pending" records associated with item A as parent, if there is a pending record, a "childOf" relationship is added between item B and item A now that item A is created in the db.

If there are multiple jobs running concurrently, here is a race condition that can occur:

| Process A | Process B |
| --- | --- |
|  | req to create item B |
|  | check db for item A and item A is not found |
| req to create item A arrives and item A is created |  |
|  | since item A doesn't exist when it was checked last time, create a pending record in db with the relationship details |
|  | the pending record stays in the DB forever since item A is already created by process A while the pending record hasn't been inserted in the DB yet |

How do I resolve this race condition? Sorry if this is too abstract. let me know if I should elaborate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a “pending” object not as a separate, different object, but in the very place where a “real” object would be, just with a flag to indicate its state.

```
CREATE TABLE object (
   name varchar(100)
      CONSTRAINT object_pkey PRIMATY KEY,
   pending boolean DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL
);
```

Now I would add a regular object like this:

```
INSERT INTO object (name)
VALUES ('A')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT object_pkey
DO UPDATE SET pending = FALSE;
```

A pending object is inserted like this:

```
INSERT INTO onject (name, pending)
VALUES ('A', TRUE)
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT object_pkey
DO NOTHING;
```

Then you don't need to check for existence before you add an object, and the race condition is gone. `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` is designed to be atomic and free from race conditions.

Comment: Didn't know postgres has an atomic "upsert" operation. Very cool, this answers my question, tysm!